# Очень неуверен(н)а / не уверен(н)а

Tags: орфография

Как правильно, если имеется в виду, что 'она очень застенчива'?

> Она очень неуверенна / не уверенна / неуверена / не уверена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Она **очень неуверенна (застенчива)**.*

**Общий прядок решения**

1. Заходите **на Грамота.ру**

**НЕУВЕРЕННЫЙ.**
Русский орфографический словарь:
неуверенный; **кр. ф. -ен, -енна, прил.**

Большой толковый словарь русского языка

**НЕУВЕРЕННЫЙ**, -ая, -ое; -рен, -ренна, -ренно. 1. Такой, которому не свойственна уверенность в ком-, чём-л.; **нерешительный**. Человек он был робкий, н. Н. в себе. Н. в правильности решения. // Выражающий нерешительность, свидетельствующий об отсутствии уверенности. Н. ответ. Он подтвердил согласие неуверенным кивком. Сказать неуверенным голосом. 2. **Нетвёрдый, неустойчивый.** Н-ая походка. Сделал несколько неуверенных шагов. Неуверенно, нареч. Н. отвечать, взглянуть. Чувствовать себя н. Она ходила

2. Наречие ***очень*** усиливает утвердительное значение.
3. **Вывод.**  Это прилагательное.  Две буквы ***НН***, **слитное написание НЕ.**

**Примеры с НН:**

Если же вы похожи на меня, то ваша речь **сбивчива и неуверенна,** вы растягиваете слова и сами не верите в то, что говорите.

Но в обычной жизни она была на удивление **неуклюжа и неуверенна,** вечно сшибала пальцы на ногах, опрокидывала вещи, стукалась головой.

Она рассказала, что..не может научиться управлять своими подчинёнными, потому что **слишком неуверенна** в общении с ними.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ**

**Сравнить** (при наличии **зависимого** слова **в себе**):

**№ 241061**
Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "Я очень неуверенна в себе" или "Я очень не уверена в себе"
**ОТВЕТ**.
Правильно: *я очень **не уверена в себе**.*

В то же время [на практике](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5) можно встретить **варианты**: неуверенна в себе/**не уверена в себе**.

**Еще ответ Грамоты:** № 249229. Как правильно писать:  я уверена или я уверенна? Будьте уверенны или уверены?
**ОТВЕТ.**
Если **нет зависимых слов**, то верно: **я уверенна**, будьте уверенны (но: я уверена **в своей правоте**).

Также: **УВЕРЕННЫЙ**. Русский орфографический словарь
уверенный; кр. ф. прич. -ен, -ена; кр. ф. прил. -ен, -ена (**с дополн.:** она уверена в своей правоте) и -ен, -енна (без дополн.: она спокойна и уверенна; движения её уверенны); будь уверена, будьте уверены (не сомневайся, не сомневайтесь).

**Общий вывод по теме:**

***Уверенный и неуверенный*** — это **прилагательные**, но не причастия (обозначают качественный признак, а не действие). В то же время в краткой форме прилагательное может вести себя **как причастие**: **она уверена / не уверена** в своей правоте (при наличии **зависимых** слов в виде **дополнения**).